# ReactJs - is it possible to set the url or querystring based on state of component tree

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a component that has several nested components, specifically tabs, pills, etc.  No all are visible at any one time.

I want to be able to set their default state/props based on the URL parameters (or URL) but I'm not clear how to achieve this in React.

For example, I have a component with two tabs (bootstrap).  When the user selects the second tab, can i modify the URL with a parameter so that is the page is refreshed, the state of the currently selected tab is retained.

I've included the `Router` but cannot find any simple examples of what I'm trying to achieve.

What I'd like to be able to do is access/parse the query string parameters and set the state and ultimately properties of the child components.

Any advice is really welcome.

I can provide example of the tab component, but don't think it would add any value to the question.

Comment: I'm using Reflux too, so is it possible to somehow listen for Router action that puts URL params in store?

Answer (score 1):

The way I've gone about this it to take advantage of React `context`s. It's an undocumented but powerful feature that kind of acts like mutable props that can be accessed by a component and all its children.

I suggest Googling about it. It's a bit tough to wrap your mind around, but starts to make sense once you play with it. Here is an example excerpt from some code I am working on right now:

```
var React = require('react');

var Router = require('react-router'),
    Route = Router.Route,
    RouteHandler = Router.RouteHandler;

var ReactBootstrap = require('react-bootstrap'),
    DropdownButton = ReactBootstrap.DropdownButton,
    Nav = ReactBootstrap.Nav,
    Navbar = ReactBootstrap.Navbar;

var ReactRouterBootstrap = require('react-router-bootstrap'),
    MenuItemLink = ReactRouterBootstrap.MenuItemLink;

var Nav = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Navbar brand='My Cool Page!' inverse toggleNavKey={0}>
        <Nav right eventKey={0}> {}
          <DropdownButton eventKey={2} title='Projects'>
            <MenuItemLink eventKey="1" to="myCoolPage" params={{ awesomeName: "matt" }}>Go to My Cool Page!</MenuItemLink>
          </DropdownButton>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar>
    );
  }
);

var MyCoolPage = React.createClass({
  contextTypes: {
    router: React.PropTypes.func
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      awesomeName: ''
    };
  },
  componentWillMount: function() {
    // Called once before the first render
    this.getAwesomeName();
  },
  componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
    // Called when props change after the first render
    // From my testing, this is also called when a context changes
    this.getAwesomeName();
  },
  getAwesomeName: function() {
    var { router } = this.context;
    var awesomeName = router.getCurrentParams().awesomeName;

    this.setState({awesomeName: awesomeName});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <h1>My awesome name is: {this.state.awesomeName}</h1>
    );
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Nav />
        <RouteHandler {...props} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var routes = (
  <Route handler={App}>
    <Route name="myCoolPage" path="myCoolPage/:awesomeName" handler={MyCoolPage} />
  </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, Router.HashLocation, function (Root) {
  React.render(<Root/>, document.body);
});
```