# Pair URL with specific state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I am working on a website using react, I have a few different pages you can navigate to without refreshing the page or anything, just moving objects in and out of view, based on a `currentPage` variable.

Basically I want to be able to enter a specific link to take me to a certain page, ie *http://my-website.com/about* would execute `this.setState({currentPage:'about'})`.

I would also like to have the url change as you change pages, if you click on "shop" the url changes to *http://mywebsite.com/shop*.

I'm sorry if this question is somewhat vague, I'm not sure how else to describe what I am trying to accomplish. If anything is unclear feel free to ask me.

Comment: I would add the tag `react-router`. It's probably what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Looking into react-router rn.

Comment: You should look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31880856/reactjs-is-it-possible-to-set-the-url-or-querystring-based-on-state-of-compone

Comment: @Gabrial I would really prefer to use something more reliable than React Context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [React-Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) for this.  `React-Router` makes use of the [History Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) to watch the active url and change your view based on the active URL.